# What is different between CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS and CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4 in curl option

Tags: curl, dns

What is the specific difference between the two codes below?

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/foo.bin");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS, "192.168.0.100");
  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/foo.bin");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4, "192.168.0.100");
  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Mainly it is a question related to `CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS` and `CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS.html and https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4.html to see the difference, mainly:

- "Pass a char * that is the list of DNS servers to be used instead of the system default" for `CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS`
- "Set the local IPv4 address that the resolver should bind to." for `CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4`

The second case should rarely be needed, it forces a specific local IPv4 address (if the box has more than one) for any outgoing DNS queries.

The first option sets which servers to contact.